# Logic Testing on iOS devices is not supported?

Tags: iphone, ios, sentestingkit

I am using the SenTestingKit to Unit Test, but I get the following message

> Logic Testing on iOS devices is not supported. You can run logic tests on the Simulator.

How can I do this?

Comment: Please take a moment to write a sensible, easily understandable question.

Comment: Looks like you need to do your logic testing on the simulator.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Logic tests only work on the simulator, you need to switch to the simulator, i.e.

[image]

Logic tests require a special unit test launcher which is not installed on actual devices.

If you want to run your tests on an actual device you can convert to application unit tests.  These are essentially the same but you application gets launched first (as a 'host') and your tests get run along side them.  This means your tests can run on any device that your application supports.  The only disadvantage is that your actual app will be running which can interfere with your test, especially if you use a lot of notifications.

Answer (score 30):

You need to have a **Host Application**

[image]

> **Note** that the image is pointing to the `General` tab of **Test** target's configurations.

Comment: FYI, this is not relevant for a project that is a framework

Comment: @OhadM Disagree.  You just need to create a new “TestHost” app target in your framework project settings— just a basic Single View App will do, with no customization beyond adding your framework to the Embedded Binaries build setting.  _Easy._

Comment: I don't have option to select app.

Answer (score 0):

we have to build and test our project in cxode only through webdriverAgrentRunner. select real device : webdriverAgentRuuner>>device name

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking this question for Automation testing then "YES, you have to change the WebDriverAgentRunner to a Real device and run the test again". The error will be disappeared

Answer (score 0):

Quanlong's answer is correct, but it doesn't describe the details. Here are the needed steps in order to test a framework on a real device:

1. Click the + sign under the list of targets and add a target of type "Application". "TestHost" is a good name.
2. Under the General tab of the **Tests** target, add TestHost as the "Host Application"
3. Under the "General" tab of the **TestHost** target, add the framework itself to the list of "Frameworks, Libraries and Embedded Content"
4. If the framework uses Pods, edit the Podfile, add a *target ‘TestHost’ do* section and make sure all pods are also installed into the TestHost target