# XCode-bot build failed on physical devices

Tags: ios, swift, continuous-integration, xcode-bots, xcode-server

today I have attached a real device for the first time to my XCode server (Xcode 7.3.1, iOS 9.3.4) and this is what i got :

```
xcodebuild: error: Failed to build workspace xxxxxxxx with scheme xxxxxxxx.  
Reason: Logic Testing Unavailable
```

My bot have a debug schema and some unit and UI tests, if i detach the iphone everything works well on simulators.

Someone have already encountered this issue ? Did you found a solution to solve ?

Comment: Does your phone have internet connectivity?

Comment: @Mr.UB yes, devices are actually connected to WIFI with internet

Comment: @ClémentRoulland, did you figure out this issue ?

Comment: @user2924482 my solution to solve just below

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Logic Testing on iOS devices is not supported?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8454935/logic-testing-on-ios-devices-is-not-supported)

Answer (score 0):

Physical devices can only run targets embedded in App.
To handle this error, you should check `Allow testing Host Application APIs` and select your app in your test target `General` tab

Comment: If this answers your question, please mark it as answer. Even if you answered your own question.

Comment: Does not work for me, I have `Allow testing Host Application APIs` and still the issue